# Why does my layout appear like this when floated?

Tags: css, css-float

I've codes below:

(Please check out codes below on Google Chrome 8+)

codes 1:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>An HTML5 document</title>
<div style="background:red; height:300px; width:1500px;">
    WWWWWWW<br>WWWWWWW<br>WWWWWWW<br>WWWWWWW<br>WWWWWWW<br>WWWWWWW
    <img src="http://www.google.com/images/logos/ps_logo2.png" style="float:left;" width="900" height="230">
</div>
<div style="background:green; color:yellow; font-weight:bolder; height:300px; width:1000px;">
    asc aca ascacaaaaaa<img style="vertical-align:top; float:left;" src="http://i3.ytimg.com/vi/F5qniuZG8Rg/default.jpg">Q
</div>
```

Why the second image displays at the second line after character `Q`?

I don't want to change codes 1. I only wanna know the reason why codes 1 displays so strange. I think the second image should display at the left of characters `ascacaaaaaa`. Just like codes 2 below:

codes 2:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>An HTML5 document</title>
<div style="background:red; height:300px; width:1500px;">
    WWWWWWW<br>WWWWWWW<br>WWWWWWW<br>WWWWWWW<br>WWWWWWW<br>WWWWWWW
    <img src="http://www.google.com/images/logos/ps_logo2.png" style="float:left;" width="900" height="230">
</div>
<div style="background:green; color:yellow; font-weight:bolder; height:300px; width:1000px;">
    asc aca ascacaaaaaab<img style="vertical-align:top; float:left;" src="http://i3.ytimg.com/vi/F5qniuZG8Rg/default.jpg">Q
</div>
```

Thank you!

Comment: If you want to work with css you have to do some correct html : html , body tag, correct doctype (http://www.w3.org/QA/2002/04/valid-dtd-list.html), close your tag ("<br/>" ,"<img/>"). CSS won't react in a good way if your html is like this.

Comment: My codes are **HTML5** code. It's validated successfully by W3C. http://validator.w3.org

Comment: it's valid indeed, ... are every browser html5 compatible ? You target only IE9, last chrome and firefox ? If yes, indeed you can write the worst html code you want. (I have a different output with EVERY last 5 version of IE) , but still it's valid ^^

Comment: @remi: experimenting with the possibilities of HTML5 does not mean producing a website for a full audience...

Comment: @remi bourgarel @bazmegakapa view-source:http://www.google.cn/ First, what I write is validated HTML code. Second, what I write is validated HTML5 code. HTML code can be displayed successfully in all the web browsers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrapping text around an image is easy when using the CSS Float attribute. You have a choice to either float the picture to the left or to the right and the rest is done for you.

in this code u write images to left so it will always stay at left doesn't matter where is your text.

Comment: I wanna know the reason why codes 1 displays so strange. I think the second image should display at the left of characters ascacaaaaaa. Just like codes 2. Thanks.

Comment: you need to read this http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/05/01/css-float-theory-things-you-should-know/

Answer (score 0):

Your first image is pushing it down. Try adding clear: left; on the second div (depending on what you want to achieve).

**UPDATE:** After you posted your second version, I checked it out in Firefox. They display just the same way, the only difference is that you have a longer text in No.2. :). When you float the image, you take it out from its normal inline flow, that's why inline text displays this way. The image does not appear next to the left of the beginning of the text, because another floated object (big picture), pushes it down.

**UPDATE 2:** OK, checking out your latest codes (Chrome 8) now I see a difference. 'ascacaaaaaaQ' (code 1) stays next to the Google logo, while 'ascacaaaaaabQ' (code 2) goes to the next line under the logo. And that's simply because the second one is too long (it's one 'word', so won't break) to fit in the small space between the logo and the right border of the green div. Still for me, (in code 2) the second image does not appear to the left of 'ascacaaaaaa', it's right under it.

Comment: I don't want to change codes 1. I wanna know the reason why codes 1 displays so strange. I think the second image should display at the left of characters ascacaaaaaa. Just like codes 2. Thanks!

Comment: @Wei: if you are not satisfied with my answer, pls tell me which browser you are checking in, because I don't see any difference.

Comment: I think you need to check out this problem on Google Chrome browser. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The first image is so wide, that it can't fit on the same line. And even though it would fit, it still would not be in the same line as the text in the parent div element. float:left; means that the image is rendered outside of the normal flow.

Comment: I wanna know the reason why codes 1 displays so strange. I think the second image should display at the left of characters ascacaaaaaa. Just like codes 2. Thanks!

Comment: Add `clear:both;` to the second div element. That way the floated image in the first div won't affect the rendering in the second one.

Comment: Thanks. I know this. And I don't want to change codes 1. I wanna know why it doesn't displays at the left of characters `ascacaaaaaa` just like **codes 2**.

Comment: When using CSS floats, the floated element is not part of the normal flow. So when you float two images to left, they both try to fit themselves in the same row. Because your first image is so wide, the second one does not fit in the same row as the first one. Now the second image is put in the left side of its parent element.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I find my question will happen on Google Chrome. Can you check out this problem in Chrome 8+ again? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

It is because your first image is tall enough that it extends down into the second `div`, so it appears to the left of your text (since it is set to float).

If you add some space to break up the two `div` elements, then you will see the second image in the place that you want. Try adding the style `margin-top: 150px;` or `clear:left;` to the second `div` to see this.

Comment: I wanna know the reason why codes 1 displays so strange. I think the second image should display at the left of characters ascacaaaaaa. Just like codes 2. Thanks.