# A strange CSS problem

Tags: css, css-float

I've codes 1 and codes 2 below:

(Please check out codes below on Google Chrome 8+)

codes 1:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>An HTML5 document</title>
<div style="background:red; height:300px; width:1500px;">
    WWWWWWW<br>WWWWWWW<br>WWWWWWW<br>WWWWWWW<br>WWWWWWW<br>WWWWWWW
    <img src="http://www.swliuxue.com/newindex/uploadfile/201011/18/162266581.jpg" style="float:left;" width="900" height="230">
</div>
<div style="background:green; color:yellow; font-weight:bolder; height:300px; width:1000px;">
    asc aca ascacaaaaaa<img style="vertical-align:top; float:left;" src="http://i3.ytimg.com/vi/F5qniuZG8Rg/default.jpg">Q
</div>
```

codes 2:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>An HTML5 document</title>
<div style="background:red; height:300px; width:1500px;">
    WWWWWWW<br>WWWWWWW<br>WWWWWWW<br>WWWWWWW<br>WWWWWWW<br>WWWWWWW
    <img src="http://www.swliuxue.com/newindex/uploadfile/201011/18/162266581.jpg" style="float:left;" width="900" height="230">
</div>
<div style="background:green; color:yellow; font-weight:bolder; height:300px; width:1000px;">
    asc aca ascacaaaaaab<img style="vertical-align:top; float:left;" src="http://i3.ytimg.com/vi/F5qniuZG8Rg/default.jpg">Q
</div>
```

I wanna know why 2 codes above displays different.

Comment: font-weight:bolder;

Is that a real css rule?

If its not then thats your problem

Comment: only difference between #1 and #2 is the text before the left float image... `asc aca ascacaaaaaa != asc aca ascacaaaaaab`

Comment: @benhowdle89 it is real. It's bolder than bold!

Comment: Why the second image displays at the the second line in codes 1? (compare with codes 2)

Comment: As i Said in your previous post : fix your html ! (doctype, html, head,body, closed tag) etc ... and you'll be able to debug your css. This HTML should not work, browser are really nice to accept it.

Comment: You should try to separate the HTML from the CSS, since only the CSS matters here, and inline styles are *really* hard to read

Comment: These might help: http://jsfiddle.net/zeF8C/ and http://jsfiddle.net/TKXNE/

Comment: I don't understand the question either... Please be more specific.

Comment: I wanna know why the second image displays at the the second line in codes 1? (compare with codes 2) Thanks!

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4884860/a-question-about-css-float isn't it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In what way are they diferent? The only difference I can see is that the 'Q' gets wrapped round after the picture. This is because the picture is floated left.

Comment: I wanna know why the second image displays at the second line after `Q` in codes 1? I think the second should displays at the left of `ascacaaaaaa` just like the situation in codes 2. Thanks!

Comment: it's because the lines of text are different lengths, so it's wrapping. Try making the lines longer in a 1 and 2 and you'll see it...